# Nodejs hosting for site, not based on express ? :) 

Tags: node.js, module, hosting, express

I made a small website on nodejs, without using any framework, just including simple modules, only for the needs of the site.

And now, when the time for deploy has come - all the hosting variants I can find require express.

Do you know any that doesn't?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it uses mysql, so I'll need mysql, and also uses imagemagick. But of course, I can check these two on the specific hosting providers ... just have to overcome the first obstacle - the requirement of express.

Comment: Heroku doesn't require Express; the example in the getting started guide _uses_ Express, but it is not required. In fact, I cannot think of a single Node.js host that requires that your app be built with Express.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://nodejitsu.com, It has more features than Heroku or other nodejs hosting sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a paid VPS (Virtual Private Server)
and Setup the environment as you want.
There are plenty of those out there like digitalocean, Amazon AWS,etc.

Comment: That's what I went for at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) ?

Or you can buy a server by Amazon AWS or Rackspace.

Comment: I see that heroku requires your app to be built on express ... I saw it in the getting started guide ...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much work you want to do and the price. if you don't mind setting up a VPS there's linode.com. If you want simple (PaaS) there's nodejitsu.com, nodester.com or nodesocket.com.